# Why did David Ricardo coin "rent", to signify income from a factor of production that exceeds the minimum necessary (to beget that factor)?

Tags: etymology

1. At the time that Ricardo (1772-1823) coined "rent", did  "rent" already signify Modern English's lay meaning of 'rent' (tenant's regular payment to a landlord for the use of property or land)? How prevalent was this ordinary meaning?
2. If so, why did Ricardo still coin "rent" and beget this ambiguity? To avoid ambiguity, why didn't he employ a different term to signify to mean Marginal Product —  Opportunity Cost? Undeniably, this economics meaning of "rent" confuses laypeople.

[Rent Seeking - Econlib](https://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/RentSeeking.html)

> But why do economists use the term “rent”? Unfortunately, there is no good reason. [David Ricardo](https://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/bios/Ricardo.html) introduced the term “rent” in economics. It means the payment to a factor of production in excess of what is required to keep that factor in its present use. So, for example, if I am paid $150,000 in my current job but I would stay in that job for any salary over $130,000, I am making $20,000 in rent.

> #### rent

> English has two words *rent*. [1.] The one
> meaning ‘payment’ [12] comes via Old French
> *rente* from Vulgar Latin **rendita*, a noun use of
> the feminine past participle of **rendere* ‘give
> back’ (source of English *render*).
> [2.] *Rent* ‘tear, rift’
> [16] comes from the verb *rend* [OE], which goes
> back to Old English *rendan*. Its ultimate
> antecedents are not known, although it may be
> related to Sanskrit *rándhra-* ‘split’.

John Ayto, *Word Origins* (2005 2e), p 421. I read [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rent#etymonline_v_10433).

Comment: You'd probably be better asking on an economics or philosophy forum. The citation indicates that the reason isn't connected with past English usage and is a coinage of Ricardo. Idiosyncratic usage by an individual is off-topic.

Comment: @StuartF "Idiosyncratic usage by an individual is off-topic." This isn't idiosyncratic usage. Modern economics uses "rent" according to Ricardo's definition.